# css tint get smaller

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a button out of image and tint the image. What i tried was this:

```
.tinted-image {

    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;

    background:
    /* top, transparent red */
    linear-gradient(
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45),
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)
    ),
    /* bottom, image */
    url(facebook-icon.png);

    background-size: 10% auto;

    background-repeat: repeat;


}
```

This works, but it make many copy's of the image. So i I placed:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Now it works... but the tint area is not `300x200` anymore. Please help me to keep the tint size and only resize the image

Comment: could you add your markup or make a complete demo?  This might help you get started: http://jsfiddle.net/atfsLmep/.

Answer (score 0):

For resizing the background image, you should try out the `background-size` property. Using it you can specify how to scale your background image.

What you probably need is:

```
background-image: url(...) center;
background-size: cover;
```

Here's the nice illustration taken from w3.org website:

[image: background-size property]

The most interesting are `convain` and `cover`. The difference is:

- `contain` - fits an image completely into your element;
- `cover` - resizes an image to completely cover your element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS filter.

```
filter: sepia(1) saturate(10) brightness(0.4) hue-rotate(300deg);
```

`sepia` will give you a sepia tone, and `hue-rotate` will change the sepia tones to other colors depending on the rotation. `300deg` will make it reddish.
Since sepia is not a "pure" tone, playing with `saturate`and `brightness` values will help you fine tuning the result.